# How to get the file extension of file uploaded

Tags: php

How to get the file type of file uploaded? If it's `.ppt`,`.docx`,`.pdf`,`.png`,`.mp4` etc. Can someone help me about this? I'm starting to learn file uploading. Give me some clues please. Just a newbie to php.

here's my code.

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
{    

    $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $folder="uploads/";

    // new file size in KB
    $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
    // new file size in KB

    // make file name in lower case
    $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
    // make file name in lower case

    $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

    if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
    {
        $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(file,size) VALUES('$final_file','$new_size')";
        mysql_query($sql);
        ?>
        <script>
        alert('successfully uploaded');
        window.location.href='index.php?success';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script>
        alert('error while uploading file');
        window.location.href='index.php?fail';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Try this:

$_FILES['file']['type'];

Comment: Quick, everybody upload a file named "',0); drop table tbl_uploads; --"!

Comment: It returned the data like this `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` So long. How can i make it specific like `.docx`?

Comment: There is an option to accept the answer. By clicking on it it shows a check mark on it.

Comment: The type of document is diff for machine to machine so you cannot just use .doc or .docx.

Comment: There's a difference between a *file type* (the "long" stuff) and a *file name extension*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: this way the programmer could just accept file with .mp4 extension and user could give mov file with .mp4 extension. a fake file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `pathinfo()` function.

Answer (score -4):

Just try this

```
<?php

echo filetype('/etc/passwd');  // file type
echo filetype('/etc/');        // dir type

?>
```

Comment: Same answer as Mohamed Nazir, it just returns, if it is a file or a directory or a link, but not the extension.

Comment: Try this using pathinfo() - 

$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);